# put out of spec chipset on old board?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, upgrade, chipset

I'm thinking of upgrading the old board and cpu in laptop.  can I solder/replace the Intel® 82GL40 Graphics and Memory Controller Hub with a GMCH other than that covered in Intel brief (later year GMCH)? Want more memory for this old laptop.

Comment: Where you going to get a motherboard for a laptop, they are custom made for each laptop enclosure? You cannot do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The only laptop upgrades I recommend are those which do not require soldering, or a complete motherboard replacement, such as one outfit is occasionally offering for X60/61 ThinkPads.

You may have the mechanical skills to remove one chip, but what's on the traces on the multiple layers of the motherboard won't change, and neither will the rest of the chip set.

Do you have circuit-level documentation to see what other ICs would require change? If not, it's a counterproductive venture.

Comment: the board is compatible with GS45, GM45 AND GL40 (installed, Max RAM 4gb).  This laptop is slow and I like it so, GS/GM45 is Max RAM 8gb.  You understood.  My question was, can I install a circuit chip of a later year - tech doesn't improve that fast.  nvme just got here, I heard.  manuallibs.com Specs are messed up.  install a 2 processor CPU, too.  that's what I'm thinking.  Got a spare laptop under the couch I never use anyway.  thanks for the opinion.

Comment: @chlyde Technology, indeed, does not change that fast; but I have seen entirely different trace layouts made to accommodate the change of one component on a motherboard.